# RegEx substract text from inside

Tags: regex

I have an example string:

> *DataFromAdHoc(cbgv)

I would like to extract by RegEx:

> DataFromAdHoc

So far I have figured something like that:

```
^[^#][^\(]+
```

But Unfortunately without positive result. Do you have maybe any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Your regex looks for a string at beginning of line `^` and your example obviously doesn't have the match at beginning of line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you tried `^[^#][^\(]+` would match:

- From the beginning of the string, it should not be a # `^[^#]`
- Then match until you encounter a parenthesis (I think you don't have to escape the parenthesis in a character class) `[^\(]+`

So this would match `*DataFromAdHoc`, including the `*`, because it is not a `#`.

What you could do, it capture this part `[^\(]+` in a group like `([^(]+)`

Then your regex would look like:

[`^[^#]([^(]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/aT9FBG/1)

And the `DataFromAdHoc` would be in group 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`^\*(\w+)\(\w+\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/J0IEdJ/1)

It just gets everything between the `*` and the stuff in brackets.

Your answer may depend on which language you're running your regex in, please include that in your question.